# Is there a awk command for searching if a user is logged on?

Tags: awk

I'm not sure how awk could allow you to view if someone is online since it's used for manipulating text files. I know how to do it with the grep command which is like

```
 who | grep 'name'
```

and then it would show if that person logged in. The syntax for awk is

```
awk options 'selection _criteria {action }' input-file
```

How would you be able to find someone using awk if it's usually used for manipulating files?

Comment: `awk` doesn't really care if the input comes from a file or stdin.

Comment: You can pipe to awk the same way you can pipe to grep.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -

is_logged_in() {
  who | USER=$1 awk -v ret=1 '
    $1"" == ENVIRON["USER"]"" {ret = 0; exit}
    END {exit(ret)}'
}

if is_logged_in root; then
  echo root is logged in
fi
```

That defines a `is_logged_in` *shell* function, that takes a user name as argument. We feed the output of `who` to `awk` to which we've passed the function argument in the `USER` environment variable.

The `awk` code processes each record in turn. If the first field in the record is equal to the value of that environment variable (here appending `""` to operands to force a string comparison), then we exit with a 0 (success) exit status.

That function can then be used in `if` statements to check whether a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of one of the possible ways to use awk and external commands:

```
is_logged($1) { print $1, "is present!"}

function is_logged(x,a){                     ## a local var
  "who|grep -w " x | getline a
  return a
}
```

And then:

```
$ awk -f test
abc
Darunia
```

-->
`Darunia is present!`